# How to do continuous query in Apache Ignite using Python?

Tags: python, ignite

I have gone through the Ignite document https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/continuous-queries, examples provided are in Java.

The link of examples in Github https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/datagrid/CacheContinuousQueryExample.java is too with Java.

How can I achieve the same using Python, any lead is well appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thin clients such as Python client do not support continuous queries currently. So your best bet is to write some Java and deploy it into your Ignite nodes.

Comment: do Python client supports pub-sub in ignite?

Comment: I don't think so, thin client has no delivery guarantees so all the ways of doing pub-sub require thick client, which is available in Java/C++/C#